# Query on Oracle scheduler

Tags: oracle, job-scheduling, dbms-scheduler

I have a requirement in which I need to call a process which sends a perticular message for every X days for a customer till N days.

Basically, it's like the process runs every day fetching the customers into cursor then the process should check when was the last message sent for each customer if it was sent exactly X days before  then I need to send the message to those customers.

I can handle this in the process by adding a extra column to track last notification date and refer that for sending. But it will be a performance hit..

So Can any one suggest me if there is a simpler way to handle this .

Kindly let me know if you need clarification on any part

Comment: Your cursor query should have a predicate that applies the filter on the last notification date. An index on that column may (or may not) help with performance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that would be a performance bump !

If you are adding the a column in the same table , anyway only one query is gonna be executed. So I didn't likely to be a performance bump.